# Excel VBA autofilter a range of numbers

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Hey everyone I am having trouble using the autofilter function in vba.  In one of my filter criteria I am trying to set it so it filters out any numbers greater than 99999 (it is filtering out zipcodes and sometimes there is an extra number added to the end).  I have tried a couple different things and cant seem to get this thing to work.  Every other line works as intended but the line I put the comment indicating.  Thank you for the help!

```
shFullYearData.Range(shFullYearData.Cells(1, 1), shFullYearData.Cells(1, LastColumn)).Select
'shFullYearData.Range("A1:Z1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
shFullYearData.Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=PWSelection
shFullYearData.Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=">=1"

'''shFullYearData.Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:="<100000",'''
'This line above isn't working properly to filter out any numbers above 100,000   
            
shFullYearData.Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "12/31/2019")
shFullYearData.Range(StartCell, shFullYearData.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Key2:=Range("B1"), Header:=xlYes
enter image description here
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message, or the behaviour which is not expected? Also what is shFullYearData? named table, pivot table, named range?

Comment: There is no error message it just doenst filter properly and shFullYearData is the sheet its applying the filter to, all of the other filters work as expected just the one that I commented on does not it removes all selection

Comment: That filter criteria works for me - is it possible your numbers are not actually numbers but text?

Comment: There is one thing in there that is text would that affect the filter at all? All the rest are numbers

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem by inserting text, my script still works fine. Can you print out startcell and lastrow and lastcolumn? Maybe you have a problem with the range? You can print it by using: debug.print

Comment: Well I don't believe that I would have a problem with my range as the range I am using works for all of the other filters, and when I printed the range to check it was outputting the correct range

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the data? like 10 rows or something, might be as tim williams pointed out a probelm with formatting. Also does the line on its own (no previous other filtering) work?

Comment: I tried running it as the first filter and not running any of the other filters and it still didn't work as I wanted,  I found that when I selected the cell and clicked into the editing bar up top it changed the cells contents from the left ot the right and it seemed to work then so im inclined to think its a formatting issue,  I just don't really know how to fix the formatting because Im not going to click through 2800000 rows of data

Comment: this means your numbers are formatted as strings, therefore the filtering based on numbers wont work. I added a small macro to my answer, simply select all numbers which are formatted as string (they are on the left side and usually have a green triangle in the upper left cornor of the cell) then execute the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Does: `Operator:=xlAnd` fix your problem?

```
.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
        "<999999", Operator:=xlAnd
```

If the numbers are formatted as strings (the are on the left side on the cell and have a green triangle in the upper left cornor of the cell) you can use the following macro to convert them to numbers.

```
Sub string_to_numb()

For Each cel In Selection.Cells

    cel.Value = cel * 1

Next
End Sub
```

After that filtering shoudl work, because before that vba was unable to filter numbers, because there were no numbers, only text consisting of numbers.

Comment: I just tried this and it only filters the number that is closest to 99999, which is only 1 zipcode out of the 20+ that should be showing

Answer (score 0):

Going by what @Andreas suggested and what you tried  re: the filters, I don't think you have any other choice: your going to have to change/ , add, /amend/  your data in R. Even if only temporarily.

First, you can sort your table on field 18 seperately first - *****don't filter!*** - ****sort!****** - (**sort seperately anything like text as text, anything like number as #**), and apply this macro to the 200000+ cells which are comming out as text formats

```
Sub Addtext()
Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In Selection
            myCell.Value = "ZIP: " & myCell.Value
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Alternatively if you are really averse to sorting you can try this instead over the range.

```
   Sub Addtexttonumbers()
    Dim myCell As Range
        For Each myCell In Selection
        
        If IsNumeric(myCell.Value) = False Then
        myCell.Value = myCell.Value
        Else:
        
                myCell.Value = "ZIP: " & myCell.Value 
                
                End If
        Next
        
    End Sub
```

[ Re this 2nd macro to alter data : **Good news -**  is that I have just tested isnumeric over a **text formated** number in a cell and it returns true and gives it a zip. So you might be safe using the macro above first off without sorting.

But I would sort first before just to be on safe side. **Bad news on 2nd macro** Blank cells get returned as true as well and get a "zip", so beware. **Good & bad news mix** Cells with any string (including "-", " " & blank space between any number) will return false, and not get a "zip".

info: ***a.*** it might be slow as your looping over cells, and **b.** it might  not do what you want **IF** there are "actually Numbers amongst those 200K numeric postcode cells that, even though they are formatted as text, you actually don't consider to be postcodes , and even though they look like postcodes, are not postcodes, and are actual integer type numbers you want to have as numbers" (* but then ill ask: - why have you mixed your data types?*) ]

then, which is my point:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
        "*ZIP*"
```

or

```
.AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*ZIP*"
```

as you want/need. The autofilter will work now .

Consider next time wrapping any information in you tables with chr(34) or pipe allowing you to better more accurately manage data   , handle data and more scope for flexibility .

So, heres evaluate over the range method for changing cells which you could implement column R the same sorted table if the looping over  macro isnt up to scratch

Note below: better faster way to change cell values using evaluate range method. Put in the range of the text formated number postcodes after you sort, and run. Made it last night. After my naighbours drove me mad with their parties.

```
Sub Test24()
    
      Dim rngData     As Range
        
      Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("R1:R200000")
      
      rngData = Evaluate("if(Row(1:200000),concatenate(" & rngData.Address & "," & Chr(34) & "CIP" & Chr(34) & "))")
      
      
      'End If
      
       End Sub
```

Took me 100 attempts but I got there in the end. Still want to but haven't figured out how to get an "if isnumber " statement in there (so you can do a conditional test over entire R:R ). Anyway, this is all because, imo , your going to have to, ** temporarily atleast, change the cells**  ----- as you can remove them back afterwards  ---- imo, you will in your circumstances have to add \introduce text to your cells ,,,force your columns to behave as you need , so to apply those new auto filter conditions to make your macro work .

As I said , you can change them back to pure text formatted numbers after if you want after you've done your autofilter conditions and extracted your data.

Comment: No sleep 24  hours. Wanted to go to bed last night. Hackney is desgusting. I don't know how I do it. Must slp .

Comment: I think my diary of what goes on in life/ real world while your working trying to progress is as relevent and important (context !) for future readers as are the a. Often  useful answers . Or b. the points seeking reputation chasing answers or c.  the fake cult abiding vapid ones quick point ones. Wtvr. Good night.